# postgres pg_dump DB backup

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump

I'm using pg_dump in script which runs everyday in night to take backup of multiple DBs. we have around 20 DBs and we noticed that one DB backup takes more than 6 hrs and then got failed and after that other DBs backup started. is there anyway to fine tune this? instead to pg_dump wait for many hrs to finish that broken DB backup?

Thanks

Comment: Use a real backup solution, not a dump. Look at barman or pgbackrest

Answer (score 0):

Run the dump scripts for each database in separate scripts so they  are not dependent on each other. Otherwise use the third party solutions suggested in comment.

Comment: Tasks performed by each independent **pg_dump** process can also be made asynchronous and speed up at the cost of additional CPU power. The switch is `-j njobs` or `--jobs=njobs` - [here you can find all the options](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/app-pgdump.html).